# Issues aligning equations

Tags: equations, indentation, align

I thought I was doing everything correctly, but clearly not. I want my equations (all whether I use `\begin{flalign}` or `\begin{equation}`) to be aligned each other (have the same indent), and then when using the `flalign` I want the equations to align at the `&` sign. I have put in `fleqn` in the document class, I have used `\mathindent`, however when I use `flalign` although the equation itself aligns at the `&` marks like it should, the start of the equation does not match the indent of the equation above. Currently I have the following (Excuse the massive preamble I put it in incase something was countering something else or if that is where the issue is):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{whatever}
a = b
\end{equation}

words and stuff

\begin{flalign*}
a & = b&
\\
& = c&
\\
& = d&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your example. There are irrelevant packages and commands for your issue.

Comment: It is as easy for you to remove packages from the preamble and check that the problem is still there as it is anyone else.

Comment: Has been edited, apologies.

Comment: it is still far from minimal \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}  would have been enough (I was going to post an answer but Ethan beat me to it by a second or two:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `align*` instead of `flalign*`.

Here's the output - works with all your packages:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks, just out of curiosity, what is the difference/why does this happen with flalign?

Comment: I don't know - I just guessed the fix. This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632628/left-align-block-of-equations (that should really migrate to tex.se).

Comment: @adrem7 The point is `flalign` flushes the output to the extremes in a page. To see this, look at the documentation (p.27 as printed, p.31 pdf page number): [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)