# Justifying a multiline formula

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I tried to find the answer to my incoming question on this site, but I didn't succed. Is there a way to justify formulas without using `\tabular`?

I mean, I have a multiline equation splitted with `\split` in several lines. I would like to align all of these line both on left and right, just like a justified text. Since there are a lot of summands, I could do this with `\tabular`, arranging all the summands in a table like manner. The problem is that the equation is too large and I wish there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) have you looked at the `amsmath` package and its many alignment environments (`align`, etc)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As it stands, the question raised by your posting is so broad that it's going to be rather difficult to provide concrete advice. Therefore, please augment your posting to provide an MWE (minimum working example) of what you have in terms of math expressions and what you've done so far in arranging them across lines.

Comment: see http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf it has a lot of examples

Comment: thank you. of course I should provide some example. unfortunately I'm not allowed to edit my question yet, I know that because I tried to add some "hello everyone" at the beginning, but I couldn't.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @jjdb: yes, but I realized it only after reading  cmhughes's link,  it was too late. I'm used to math.stackexchange and I thougth the same rules hold for all the stackexchange network. next time I'll write my question correctly, anyway your comments answer my question, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want right justification? For multiline equations that's not common, and perhaps not easiest to read. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108311/issues-aligning-equations/108317#108317 for how to use `align`.

Answer (score 3):

It is, to say the least, rather unusual to justify a displayed mathematical layout. It's rather hard in an AMS alignment as that is internally boxing and measuring things which tends to set glue at its natural length.

However in simple cases you can make the default glue infinitely stretch and use inline math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\thickmuskip=5mu plus 1fill
\medmuskip=4mu plus 1fill minus 3mu
\noindent X\dotfill X

\vskip\abovedisplayskip
\noindent$\displaystyle
a+b+c+d+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i +
a+b+c+d+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i +
a+b+c+d+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i+\prod_{i\in X} x_i
$\par
\vskip\belowdisplayskip

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```