# amsmath align issues with equations

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

So usually amsmath centre aligns equations by default. However, for some reason my equations are not centred. Now my Latex skills aren't bad, but this really has me stumped. I know some issues are caused by how your preambled is ordered, apparently the order packages are loaded causes issues. Hoping someone with more experience can identify the issue.

Here is my preamble with a simple working example.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black, citecolor=black}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{\textendash}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
2+2=4
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

The above simple example has left aligned the equation and I can't seem to fix the issue, I've tried a few package reorderings and nothing has worked. None of the similar questions seem to have the same issue I am having. [Issues aligning equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108311/issues-aligning-equations) is similar but not quite the same. I'd prefer to stick to article and not report (report doesn't fix the issue either).

Many thanks for the help.

EDIT: Found this while looking for equation references here on stack exchange. Very useful for a lot of math related questions http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Remove the `fleqn` option from `\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}`. [`fleqn` stands for Flush Left Equations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=44548796#44548796).

Comment: OH!! I didn't know that. I used fleqn to fix something else within an align when working on another project and didn't think about it when I copy pasted the preamble for the new assignment. Many thanks for the simple fix!

Comment: No worries. It happens for everyone :)

Comment: Is there a way to close the question but leave it available for other to see in case they have the same issue?

Comment: @Ken But why do you want to close the quesiton?

Comment: You can accept Raaja's answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of his answer), or I can vote to close it as "Off-topic because it was solved in the comments". Either way it will be available for other people to see. I'll let you choose ;)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I am in agreement with you. May be if necessary, I can delete my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments (remove the `fleqn` option).

Answer (score 2):

Remove `fleqn` and all should work out as you want. Because `fleqn` forces left alignment per se.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black, citecolor=black}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{\textendash}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
2+2=4
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image]